# Is it possible to detect section ID when moving list item between sections?

Tags: swiftui

I have two lists, one for numbers and another for alphabets.

When I long press on the rows I am able to drag and drop to reorder them.

However, SwiftUI doesn't seem to prevent items moving between different ForEach.

If I drag and drop "a" into the numbers section I would get an error.

`Sample Code`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var alphabets = ["a", "b", "c"]
    @State private var numbers = ["1", "2", "3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section("Alphabets") {
                    ForEach(alphabets, id: \.self) { alphabet in
                        Text(alphabet)
                    }
                    .onMove { fromOffsets, toOffset in
                        alphabets.move(fromOffsets: fromOffsets, toOffset: toOffset)
                    }
                }
                Section("numbers") {
                    ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                        Text(number)
                    }
                    .onMove { fromOffsets, toOffset in
                        alphabets.move(fromOffsets: fromOffsets, toOffset: toOffset)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Is it possible to prevent this error? (If I recall correctly, this doesn't seem to happen prior to iOS 16.0)

I am looking for something like this:

```
.onMove { fromOffsets, toOffset in
    if destinationSectionId == thisSectionId {
        alphabets.move(fromOffsets: fromOffsets, toOffset: toOffset)
    } else {
        do nothing
        display an animation to move the item back
    }
}
```

Thank you!